# two listviews in fragment?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm new to android development, and I have doubts about working with fragments.

I have to build an App that runs 2 **ListViews** on the **same** screen, but the list on the ***right depends on what I select in the list on the left***. I've looked through all the tutorials and samples about the working with **Fragments**, and I haven't found a way to do that succesfully.

Comment: You could use two list view in a activity and change the list of right list view "on selection changed" in the list view on the left

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959009/multiple-listview-inside-listfragment

Comment: Check this fragments tutorial out, it should lead you in the right direction: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and follow the example explained there. In the example given you have listfragment and when clicked on an Item, details will be changed. So You implement another listfragment which will display items upon selection of first listview instead of Details.

Comment: there is enough code in the example link I have given, what more I can provide you?