# 2 ListView in a ListFragment only one onListItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

As I mentioned in the title, I have 2 ListView (lets call them A and B) in a ListFragment and only one  onListItemClick.

When I click on a row of List A, my onListItemClick is called fine. But when I click on a row of List B, nothing happens.

This is what I have:

```
<!-- LIST A -->
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<!-- Separator -->
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<!-- LIST B -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listCompany"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

This is my ListFragment:

```
public class ClientsActivity extends ListFragment {
    OnClientSelectedListener mClientListener;


public interface OnClientSelectedListener {
        public void onEmployeeSelected(int id);
        public void onCompanySelected(int id);
    }

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
        mClientListener = (OnClientSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " you must implement OnClientSelectedListener ");
    }
}

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Log.e("onListItemClick","called with " + position + " : "+l.getId() + " and " + android.R.id.list);
        int id = position; 
    if (l.getId() == android.R.id.list) {
           mClienteListener.onEmployeeSelected(id);
       } else if (l.getId() == R.id.listCompany) {
           mClienteListener.onCompanySelected(id);
       }
}
```

And then in my main FragmentActivity I implement the interface OnClientSelectedListener. I think this has to be with android:id in my ListViews. I dont know how to invoke onListItemClick when a row of List B is clicked. Any help will be apreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

In the onCreateView of my ListFragment I have:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_clientes, container, false);

            //LIST A
    listEmploees(view);

            //LIST B
    listCompanies(view);
...
}

private void listCompanies(View view){
    CompanyqliteDao companyDao = new CompanyqliteDao ();
            //I get all the companies from DB
    mCursorCompany = companyDao.listCompany(getActivity());

    if(mCursorCompany.getCount()>0){
        String[] from = new String[] { "name", "phone"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewNameIzq,  R.id.textViewNameCent };
        ListView lvCompanies = (ListView) view.findViewById (R.id.listCompany);

                    //I have a custom adapter
        ListClientCursorAdapter notes = new ListClientsCursorAdapter(contexto, R.layout.activity_fila_cliente, mCursorCompany, from, to, 0);
        lvCompanies .setAdapter(notes);


        lvCompanies.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg)   {
                onListItemClick(lvCompanies,view,position,arg);
            }
        });

    }
}


private void listEmploees(View view){
    EmployeeSqliteDao employeeDao = new EmployeeSqliteDao();
            //Get the list from DB
    mCursorEmployee = employeeDao.listEmployees(getActivity());

    if(mCursorEmployee.getCount()>0){
        String[] from = new String[] { "name", "phone"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewNameIzq,  R.id.textViewNameCent};
        ListView lvEmployees = (ListView) view.findViewById (android.R.id.list);

        ListClientsCursorAdapter notes = new ListClientesCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.activity_fila_cliente, mCursorEmployee, from, to, 0);
        lvEmployees.setAdapter(notes);
                    //NOTE THAT I DONT HAVE TO SET A LISTENER FOR THIS ONE, AUTOMATICALLY
                    // THE onListItemClick IS CALLED

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need get reference of your second ListView and you need to attach onItemClickListener to it.

Because ListFragment will attach onItemClckListener for the listView having id `@id/android:list`

Try to get reference in `onCreateView`

**Edit:**

```
  ListView list2=view.findViewById(R.id.listCompany);
   list2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg)   {
            onListItemClick(adapter,view,position,arg);
    }
});
```

Comment: I did what you say, but eclipse complains: "The method setOnItemClickListener (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (ClientsActivity). I'll put more code in my question please, look at it.

Comment: @kiduxa Please try my edit. I haven't tried that, I hope this will work

Comment: still eclipse complains. Isn't there any way that the setOnItemClickListener calls anyhow to the onListItemClick that I already overridden?

Comment: @kiduxa You may be importing `onItemClickListener` of type `View`, please change that to new `AdapterView.onItemClickListener`

Comment: @kiduxa Make sure that you are using onItemClickListener of type AdapterView check imports `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;`

Comment: ok that helps but I still have one complain. Look that I implemented onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) not onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg). I tried in both manners but have problems

Comment: @kiduxa Sorry I didn't get you...what I understand is you have problem when calling  onListItemClick right?, ok try  `onListItemClick(list2,view,position,arg);`

Comment: Yes you are right! it works!!. But now I'm confuse with the other comment. Apparently I should have "One ListView per ListFragment, or multiple ListViews in one Fragment, but no two ListViews in one ListFragment". But what you say worked, now I dont know if I leave this the way it is or change it :s. What do you recomend me?

Comment: @kiduxa There is no rule that ListFragment should have only one listview. ListFragment is just like a fragment with extra implementation for ListView with id `@id/android:list`, so I don't think this will cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `ListFragment` to a `Fragment`, then reference the two `ListView`s separately and assign their listeners:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
ListView listCompany = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listCompany);

list.setAdapter(...)
list2.listCompany(...)
```

One `ListView` per `ListFragment`, or multiple `ListViews` in one `Fragment`, but no two `ListViews` in one `ListFragment`

Comment: wow this change really make me change a lot of things!. Are you sure about this? : "One ListView per ListFragment, or multiple ListViews in one Fragment, but no two ListViews in one ListFragment"

Comment: not just my opinion... another response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13959135/793607 also documentation says: ListFragment hosts a ListView object that can be bound to different data sources, typically either an array or a Cursor holding query results. Binding, screen layout, and row layout are discussed in the following sections. (note, it says "a ListView object" not "ListView objects"

Comment: wow, I see.. but the other person that commented, helped me out. Please look at it. Should I leave it this way or change it to the way you say?. I dont know if I'm going to have problems in the future.

Comment: If it works for you, then run with it!  No need to worry about theory if what you have works.

Comment: well thank you so much for your attention I really appreciate. You had helped me before and now. So thanks!!